Include a header file from 3rd party which at present at multiple paths on linux server
Platform: Linux
Scenario is like this:
I have two modules. Lets say X and Y at path /home/testuser/Test_CO/
I have a C++ file in X which is including a file "aaa.h" which is present at 2 paths.
One is
"/home/testuser/Test_CO/Y/abc/include/"
and other
"/usr/include/abc/".
The path to include from Y is already mentioned in makefile but instead of picking up from Y it is picking from "/usr/include/abc/" path
Makefile
export TAG=home/testuser/Test_CO/
INCFLAG += 
-I$(TAG)/Y/abc/include/
Now coming to cpp headerfile in X where aaa.h it is included like this:
#include"aaa.h"
but when I am changing above statement to header file inside Y like this it is working fine
#include "../Y/abc/include/aaa.h"
How to make it include without changing the include statement like above?

There is insufficient information here and it is insufficiently clear. Please edit your question to show us a Minimal Reproducible Example
that goes wrong. Tell us what is wrong with it and tell us what would be right.

If you have two include files with the same name, you have to make them different in some other way. Like using their path to differentiate. There is no magic trick that helps here.

There is no portable way.

It looks like you are missing a / after TAG=: export TAG=/home/testuser/Test_CO. Also, INCFLAG may be some proprietary configuration variable for you Makefile. The compiler follows CPATH environment variable.

The way the preprocessor looks for include files is implementation-defined by the C standard which means the behavior is specific to a given compiler. However, it is common (for example gcc) that #include "aaa.h" will search for the file relative to the path of the source file containing the include directive.
Therefore, specifying a relative path like in
#include "../Y/abc/include/aaa.h"

can be used to direct the preprocessor to a specific location.
If the include file is not found relative to the current path, then the include paths specified on the command line are searched in the order they are given. Thus, if the include directive simply provides the file name:
#include "aaa.h"

and the file is not found in the same path as the source file, then file is taken from the first path provided on the command line, in this case it must be /usr/include/abc/.
So the only way to get the file from /home/testuser/Test_CO/Y/abc/include/ instead is to change the command line such that -I /home/testuser/Test_CO/Y/abc/include/ appears before -I /usr/include/abc.
However, doing that generally will cause problems if a source file needs to include the version found in /usr/include/abc which will then be eclipsed.
If having header files with the same name cannot be avoided, then the best option is usually to specify the file with a partial path which will also make it clearer to a reader of the code which file is actually included.
In this case, this could be done by having -I /home/testuser/Test_CO/Y in the command line and include the file by
#include "abc/include/aaa.h"


There are multiple ways (actually small variations, each with its advantages and disadvantages) of doing this, I (just a matter of personal preference) would choose a model similar to Git's configuration settings ([Git-SCM]: Customizing Git - Git Configuration):

/usr/include/abc/aaa.h the most generic one, should be available everywhere (equivalent to system settings)

/home/testuser/Test_CO/Y/abc/include/aaa.h has a more local nature, but is not project local as it's needed by project X as well (equivalent to global settings)


It could be something like:

Most generic:
#include <abc/aaa.h>  // From /usr/include - which is by default in include paths


Intermediary:
#include <Y/abc/include/aaa.h>  // From /home/testuser/Test_CO

with the mention that /home/testuser/Test_CO should be manually added to include paths:
INCFLAG += -I/home/testuser/Test_CO



It's scalable, pattern can be also applied if having:

Another (global) file e.g: /home/testuser/Test_CO/Z/abc/include/aaa.h required by multiple projects (with no need to further altering include paths)

A project W that would also need it (same as X)


A project local file (/home/testuser/Test_CO/X/abc/include/aaa.h), could be refered to as (let's say - as I don't know where the source files are located inside the project):
#include "abc/include/aaa.h"  // Project local


Or each project configured with its own include paths, and then simply:
#include <aaa.h>  // Project local



The drawback is that those include paths would have to be specified in every #include directive, but it's also clear for anyone reading the code what's included (and from where), and (again) it's done in the same manner across files / projects.
